# How to deploy product using docker in few steps

Tags: github, deployment, graph, docker, graphite

I can not understand conception of Docker. I trying to install this component (graphite rendering graphs from influxdb):

https://github.com/vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb-docker

I was faced with docker at first time and it is important to deploy graphite+influxdb from that link by this work night.

The question is: if I need search github links of graphite and influxdb, install them, and after that make them work under docker?

For what docker and how quickly to deploy this project.

As I understood I need to do next steps from github link:

```
#cd /root
#yum install docker
#docker pull vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb

#git clone https://github.com/vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb-docker.git
#cd graphite-api-influxdb-docker
#ls
Dockerfile  graphite-api.sh  graphite-api.yaml  LICENSE  NOTICE  README.md
#vi graphite-api.yaml (change <host> to localhost)
#docker build .
#docker run -p 8000:8000 <image-id>  (<image-id> here i set like vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb if this true?)
```

I feel that I think in different direction and hope for a few words what u think about will a little help to me.

Comment: Just follow the `build` section in your link. Instead of `git clone`, just create a new Dockerfile as instructed in the `build` section, add a `yaml` file in the same folder, with the customization you need. Finally, build it with a name `docker build -t name .`, then `docker run -p 8000:8000 name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to clone the GitHub repository

```
git clone https://github.com/vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb-docker.git
```

Second, you have to add your own graphite-api.yaml (if you want)

Build it:

```
docker build .
```

If you need more information about how to build a Docker content from a Dockerfile, read the "Building an image from a Dockerfile" section from [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/) to know how to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile.

You can add a name with -t option (and use it as ID in the next step).

And, finally, run the content :

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 [ID]
```

[ID] is provided to you when you build the Docker content (it is explained in the link).

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: you can even skip cloning the repository; docker can directly build from a github repository; doing `docker build -t some-name github.com/vimeo/graphite-api-influxdb-docker` should make docker clone the repo and build the image

Comment: Yes but, if you want to change graphite-api.yaml, you will need to donwload it.